# PassportJS - Using multiple passports within Express application

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Suppose I need two different passports within one express application (e.g. user & room).
So I define two separate vars:

```
var passport    = require('passport');
var roomPassport = require('passport');
```

then, I initialize them with separate passport strategies:

```
require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration
require('./config/roompassport')(roomPassport); // pass passport for configuration
```

the last step is to set them as Express middleware:

```
// required for passport
application.use(session({ secret: 'ilovepassport;-)' })); // session secret
application.use(passport.initialize({ userProperty: "user" }));
application.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
application.use(roomPassport.initialize({ userProperty: "room" }));
application.use(roomPassport.session()); // persistent login sessions
application.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session`
```

however, if I did it like this, in fact roomPassport overrides passport and instead of having two objects - req.user and req.room, I have got just one req.room but initialized with user data.

It is important to mention that each passports (user or room) could authenticate independently from each other, i.e. there is a scenario where both objects `req.user` and `req.room` have to exist.

How to resolve this?

EDIT 1

Well, after few more hours, it seems that although I have to separate passport objects, after the call of `application.use(roomPassport.initialize({ userProperty: "room" }));`, things get messy - and this is because `req.login()` method works with the last attached passport. So instead of calling the correct `passport.serializeUser` method, it calls `roomPassport.serializeUser` method.

My next question - how to make `req.login()` to call the right method?

Answer (score 13):

The problem your having is that the passport module exports an instantiated Passport object when you require it. And because that object is cached by node when you require it, you get the exact same object every time.

Luckily, the passport module also gives you a [reference to the class](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/4dce9d99a009fdec8a6b83a8cbc99d119a73c561/lib/index.js#L18-L19), meaning you can do this.

```
var Passport = require('passport').Passport,
    passport = new Passport(),
    roomPassport = new Passport();
```

Now you should have two completely separate passport objects.

Comment: Thanks dude, you saved my day! It solves my problem but not completely. It seems, that I will need separate passport.sessions, since otherwise both password objects override the same cookie. So my next question is - how to setup two separate sessions (probably name them)?

Comment: I just put it as new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898629/passportjs-how-to-make-separate-passport-session

Comment: Hey, I followed your advice and also created two different passport config files to handle the two diff local strategies. However when i try to login using the original one it throws error saying "Unknown strategy local-login".

Answer (score 0):

For typescript you can import the class directly

```
import { Passport } from 'passport'

const passport = new Passport()
```

I also tried to write a full step by step here:
https://zenn.dev/theblindhawk/articles/0a5b39114b7f51