# PassportJS - How to make separate passport.session

Tags: cookies, express, passport.js

My question is related to [PassportJS - Using multiple passports within Express application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896753/passportjs-using-multiple-passports-within-express-application) topic.
So as long as I already have two separate passport instances, I realized that they both share the same cookie, created here:

```
application.use(session({ secret: 'my secret cookie', key: 'usid' }));
```

I can add one more cookie with different name using this:

```
app.use(connect.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', key: 'rsid' }))
```

However, it is not clear to me how to instruct each passport to use its own cookie.

Comment: Hey Angel . Were you able to find a solution for this problem ? I also am struggling with using multiple passport configs in my express app and make it work . Thanks.

Comment: I'm having same problem. Did u get a solution or used some workaround for that?

Comment: Is there any one has solution?

Comment: many refs for you guys
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/287
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/450
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/286
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35392317/how-to-use-two-separate-passport-instances-in-a-single-express-server-file

They work in some situations, but not my own

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the two sessions to their respective paths

```
app.use('/admin', session({ ... })
app.use('/developer', session({ ... })
```

Each session just needs to have its own `secret` and `name`.
I also tried to write a full step by step here: https://zenn.dev/theblindhawk/articles/0a5b39114b7f51

Answer (score 0):

I figured out temporary solution for passport 0.4.0 via

`passport._key = passport._sm._key  = 'customPassportSessionKey'`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by making **from the router and not from the app**. I've solved the same issue by developing something like an AuthBuilder which receives certain parameters, each instance generates a new passport that way.

```
class AuthBuilderService {
    constructor() {
        this.passport = new Passport();
        this.registerSerializers(); // Multiple serializers
        this.registerStrategies(); // Multiple strategies
    }
```

Then you can register multiple routers with the same passport and key (or just one) by calling the authbuilder.addRouter(...)

```
 addRouter(router, loginFileName, failureUrl, successUrl) {
        router.use('/login', express.static(`${__dirname}/../views/whatever`, {
            index: loginFileName,
            fallthrough: true,
        }));

        router.use(session({
            secret: 'any secret',
            key: (_isRouterA()) ? 'a' : 'b',
            resave: true,
            saveUninitialized: true
        }));

        router.use(this.passport.initialize());
        router.use(this.passport.session());

        this._configureRouter(router, failureUrl, successUrl); // There I'm handling login, logout and some middleware.

        return this;
    }
```

From the routers you want to protect:

```
    routerUsers_1.get('something_1', method)
    routerUsers_2.get('something_2', method2)
    let authBuilder = new AuthBuilderService();    
    authBuilder.addRouter(routerUsers_1, 'login_users_vip.html', '/path/failure_vip/', '/path/success_vip');
    authBuilder.addRouter(routerUsers_2, 'login_users.html', '/path/failure/', '/path/success');


    routerAdmins.get('something', methodAdmin)
    new AuthBuilderService().addRouter(routerAdmins, 'login_admins.html', '/path2/failure/', '/path2/success');
```

Then express app just use each router.

```
app.use('path-client-vip', routerUsers_1)
app.use('path-client', routerUsers_2)
app.use('path-admin', routerAdmin)
```

I'm working with 2 webapps (with different users, logins and content) in the same express app server, each webapp uses different instances of this AuthBuilderService for multiple routers using different passport, sessions, strategies and serializers between each AuthBuilderService instance.

Hope it will help somebody.