# How to use two separate passport instances in a single express server file

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

I have an express app with a user and admin section. Both will run on different ports and need different authentication. I created an app.js where I include passport and create an app as well as adminApp. Then I initialize passport for both as follows:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var app = express();
var adminapp = express();

adminapp.use(passport.initialize());
adminapp.use(passport.session());

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Now I have routes defined to listen to /auth and handle authentication. Since I am running these on different ports, I have same patterns for routes, and both are listening correctly on their ports. So lets say I have a `userSessions.js` and `adminSessions.js` files to handle the authentication routes. These are included as follows:

```
var userSessions = require('./routes/userSessions');
var adminSessions = require('./routes/adminSessions');

app.use('/auth', userSessions);
adminapp.use('/auth', adminSessions);
```

Now if I try to authenticate on the admin app, it still goes to the `passport.serializeUser` and `passport.deSerializeUser` methods of `userSessions.js`.

How can I handle this situation so that admin and user authentication are handled separately? Or am I doing this the wrong way and admin section should be handled in completely different app?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have not tried but you can look for 
[passports](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passports)

```
var Passport = require('passport').Passport,
    appPass = new Passport(),
    adminappPass = new Passport();
```