# Want passport to store req.client instead of req.user for Bearer strategy

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am a implementing Oauth2 bearer strategy to authenticate clients using passport.js. 
I use the passport-http-bearer package and implemented the following callback:

```
 passport.use(new BearerStrategy(
    function (accessToken, done) {
      Token.findOne({ token: accessToken }).populate('client').exec(function (err, token) {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }
        if (!token) {
          return done(null, false);
        }
        if (new Date() > token.expirationDate) {
          Token.remove(accessToken, function (err) {
            return done(err);
          });
        }
        if (token.client) {
          var info = { scope: token.client.scopes };
          return done(null, token.client, info);
        }
        else {
          return done(null, false);
        }
      });
    }
  ));
```

Later on I want to read the client info - which gets placed under the req.user key by the passport `done()` callback.
Is there a way to get passport to store the returned client in `req.client` variable instead of req.user?

My goal is to authenticate users and clients with the same application, therefore I can't have conflicting keys in my request.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the user property while initialising passport.

```
app.use(passport.initialize({userProperty:'client'));
```

passport will use this property to store info.

Comment: thank you! Do you know of a way to do this only for a particular strategy? I want to retrieve the client only when I use the `Bearer` strategy, while other strategies are designed to authenticate a user, and therefore I want to store them under the `req.user key`.

Comment: Since the initialization happens at the passport level ,I do  not see a way to handle that at Strategy level.

Comment: ok I guess the only way is to use 2 different instances of Passport as described here right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896753/passportjs-using-multiple-passports-within-express-application

Comment: Yes. I see thats the only option left for us.

Comment: I guess another approach could be to use the AuthInfo key that is created by the 3rd argument of the `done()` function like this: `var info = { scope: token.client.scopes, client_id: token.client._id, clientName: token.client.clientDisplayName };
          return done(null, token.client, info);`